# Can Node.js use another filename for the directory index file, instead of `index.js`?

Tags: node.js

When we write `require('some/directory')`.

It will look for `some/directory/index.js` if `some/directory` is a directory.

But what if I want to use another file name like `_index.js`? (So it can be sorted ahead its sibling files in the dir-tree.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

The default file name is hard-coded and should be either `index.js` or `index.node` according to this:

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules

Answer (score 3):

The default file name is index.js, but you can use another file through package.json.

In this file, you should have key **name**:

```
  "main": "index",
```

replace by any name you prefer, even in another directory:

```
  "main": "./lib/index",
```

see https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

Comment: Does this setting decides the index filename for all directories in a package? (I'm not 100% sure but I think this only decides the main file for the package.)

Comment: Is is only a way to tell what is the start point. I set index, but you can use toto, any word you name script used in directory. If you use toto, you must have a toto.js and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It is hardcoded inside of the node core, you can see it here in action:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js#L224

As it says in docs, first it tries to get the package from node_modules, if there is no such package - tries to get it from index.js from that folder, and as a last resort it tries to open specified (if any) package.json in that folder. If none found - it fails with an error, stating that there is no such module

Answer (score 0):

Super simple solution that works for me:

**someFileYouWantAsIndex.js**

```js
// ...code
// ...code
module.exports = { whatever };
```

**index.js**

```js
const stuff = require('./someFileYouWantAsIndex.js');
module.exports = stuff;
```

Comment: Life gets simpler `export { default } from './someFileYouWantAsIndex';`